# UIImageView.image Not Receiving Value of UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm having difficulties assigning the value of an image to an image view image. I've tested that the source image has a value at the time of assignment to the image view image, and indeed it does. However, the assignment just does't appear to happen, and the image view image remains null. Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 100.0;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString *imageName = @"http://my.domain.com/image.png";
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageName];

        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            self.imageView.image = img;//img HAS a value, but self.imageView.image does NOT receive it

            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure self.imageView isn't nil?

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar, it appears that self.imageView is nil. Silly question, but should this not be the case? I have the outlet defined as: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;` if that's of use.

Comment: You must not have connected the outlet to the image view in IB.

Comment: Thanks, the outlet was there but not connected to the UIImageView in the storyboard for some reason. If you want to add your suggestion as an answer I will selected it as best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with `UIImage`. where you alloc object of `UIImage`. Try This :

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

   [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techbeasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Wallpaper-HD.jpg"]];  // Your image URL. First check it in browser image is there.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];//img HAS a value, but self.imageView.image does NOT receive it
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's a more succinct way of doing it, however the suggestion by @rdelmar that the outlet may not be properly connected appears to have been the issue. After reconnecting the outlet, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you have to use `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_sync` pair. So the the inner block will wait till the outer block completes its execution and downloads image.

```
   dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString *imageName = @"http://my.domain.com/image.png";
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageName];

        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            self.imageView.image = img;//img HAS a value, but self.imageView.image does NOT receive it

            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
```

Then make sure the `imageView` is allocated with either by programmatically or using IB.

Comment: The outlet wasn't properly connected. Reconnecting it solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but believe I want the inner block to wait for the outer block. I want the interface to be active while the image downloads, but then to display the image once it's downloaded. Am I missing something?

Comment: put a break point inside both blocks and download a bit larger image. and see which is calling when and is inner block waits if inner block is `async` ?

Answer (score 0):

The outlet had not properly connected. Reconnecting it solved the issue.